# How to get access to variable in child class without initialize it in parent class in getter

Tags: c++

Hi there I've a little problem with my course work in university, let me show you.
I've one parent `class` called Organisation and two child classess called Insurance and Manufacturem, also I've a container Deque. Class Insurance has field called `statutory_capital` it's `float` and my task is to show `organisation`, which has `statutory_capital` more, than derived from user.

That's `Deque.h` :

```
#pragma once
#include "Organisation.h"
struct Node
{
    Node *Next;
    Organisation* data;
};

class Deque
{
public:
    void Do_request();
private:
    Node *Front;
    Node *Back;
};
```

That's `Organisation.h` :

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Organisation 
{
protected:
    int workers; 
    string name;   
    float experience; 
    //float statutory_capital; If I uncomment this and get_statutory_capital everything works
public:
    Organisation();
    Organisation(string Name, float Experience, int Workers);
    virtual void show() = 0;
    virtual string get_name();
    virtual int get_workers();
    //virtual float get_statutory_capital();
};
```

Here is method `Do_request()` to find `organisations` with statutory capital more than written by user :

```
void Deque::Do_request()
{
    if (Front == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The deque is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node *temp = Front;
    Insurance tmp;
    Insurance *ptr_insurance;
    float test_statutory_capital;
    cout << "Write the statutory capital to find: ";
    cin >> test_statutory_capital;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        ptr_insurance = new Insurance(temp->data);
        cout << "TESt" << tmp.get_statutory_capital();
        if (ptr_insurance != NULL)
        {
            if (tmp.get_statutory_capital() > test_statutory_capital)
            {
                cout << "Insurance with capital more than test: "<< temp->data->get_name() << "\n";
            }
        }
        temp = temp->Next;
    }

}
```

What should I do not adding a variable `statutory_capital` to my parent `class`Organisation, I don't need it here, cause my class Manufacture doesn't have the field statutory capital. Thanks!

Comment: Can't we see a [mcve] instead?

Comment: You only need a function in Organization, that returns 0. You can override it in Institution with one that returns a variable.

Comment: Yes, will add it in 30 minutes

Comment: thanks manni66 it worked, doesn't know if it's good:)
virtual float get_statutory_capital() {return 0;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment is tricky. Only `Insurance` has statutory_capital, but you have to find out what statutory capital an organisation has without knowing if it's an Insurance or not. So here's a contradiction. On one hand, the base class shouldn't have knowledge about its *specific* derived classes. On the other hand, you need to find out information about a specific derived class having only a bunch of base class pointers in hand.

There are several solutions out there but they all will involve different trade-offs.

You can introduce the knowledge about statutory capital to your base class. The recommended way is to add a virtual function `get_statutory_capital()`. The default implementation will return 0 (or a negative number, indicating that this organisation doesn't have a notion of statutory capital). Relevant derived classes will override it as they see fit. The downside of this is the base class potentially growing out of control as you add more and more child-specific functionality to its interface.

You can check the type of the organisation at run time (using e.g. `dynamic_cast`). If this particular organisation has statutory capital, process it; if not, leave it alone. The recommended way of doing this is creating a special class `Has_statutory_capital` with one public pure virtual method `get_statutory_capital()`. Add this base class to all organisations that have statutory_capital. The downside of this is having to use `dynamic_cast`, which makes the design more complicated and unwieldy.

You can keep organisations that have statutory capital in a separate list (again, derive them from `Has_statutory_capital`). This again makes the design more complicated, in a different way.

You can make your classes [visitable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and use the Visitor pattern to process the statutory capital information. The downside is the usual downside of the visitor pattern: a cyclic dependency.

If most of this goes over your head, don't worry and just use the first solution.